# having trouble altering DOM from function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

thanks for clicking.

I am new to JS and just like dinking around for fun but I am having trouble getting this function to work. I have tested it with google chrome `alert('incorrect');` and it works but whenever I try running a style display property nothing happens.

any help is much appreciated & thank you in advance!

```js
function validate() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "14") {
    pwForm.display.style = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="validate()" id="passwordForm">
      <input
        id="passwordPrompt"
        type="text"
        placeholder="how many years?"
        name="fname"
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: check the browser *developer* tools console to see what actually happens

Comment: copy, thank you! I'll do that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues in your code. First, the `pwForm` variable is not defined, and second, the correct property to manipulate the display style is `style.display`, not `display.style`.

Also, you probably need to stop the form submission to stay on the page.

```js
function validate() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "14") {
    document.getElementById("passwordForm").style.display = "none";
  }
  return false;//prevent the form submission to stay on the page
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()" id="passwordForm">
  <input
    id="passwordPrompt"
    type="text"
    placeholder="how many years?"
    name="fname"
  />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: i feel like a dummy!!! thank you for the taking the time to help me out Mamun